# Adding list items to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
var localPlaceholder = document.getElementById('localFiles');
                for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
                        var newList = document.createElement( "li" );
                        newList.nodeValue = entries[i].name;
                        localPlacholder.appendChild(newList);
                }
```

Does this make any sense? For some reason I am not seeing anything added  - though entries[i].name DOES return values if I debug it with alert boxes.

EDIT: localFiles is a ul

Comment: provide a full repro ...

Comment: it's an array with some sort of file objects the name property of which returns the file name as a string - it works fine inside an alert box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
newList.nodeValue = entries[i].name;
```

try:

```
newList.innerHTML = entries[i].name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply:

```
var localPlaceholder = document.getElementById('localFiles');
var newList = '';

for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    newList += '<li>' + entries[i].name + '</li>';
}

localPlaceholder.innerHTML += newList;
```

Less instances of DOM manipulation.

EDIT: consider http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/ZyU8h/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add text directly using method nodeValue to html element unless it is a text node(LI is not a text node). You need to create a text node then add it to the html element, or else, just you can simply use innerHTML.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeValue

You may try change

```
newList.nodeValue = entries[i].name;
```

to

```
newList.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entries[i].name);
```